# Android kSOAP2 2.5.X is needed

Tags: android, download, android-ksoap2

I'm trying for more then 2 days to download the kSOAP2 for android with out success.
Can any body here send me the jar file?
thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link to download Ksoap jar ..
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.5/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar

click view raw to download it..

Comment: How do i use "view raw" in IE?

Comment: see right side bottom. there is link for "View Raw File" click on it.  you can see it in IE also.

Comment: here is the link for all version of KSOAP http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/#ksoap2-android-assembly%2F2.5.5